# Using MOUSEBUTTONDOWN in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I am trying to do some very basic things in pygame.  It is my first few days using it so I am a beginner.  I am trying to change the color of something whenever I press it with the mouse.  I know how to change the colors by timing which is what I have my code down below.  I am trying to change the color of the cloud in my code below, if you run it you will see the cloud is the top left and I have it changing between white and black every three seconds but I want it to change based on mousebuttondown.  Thanks

```
import pygame, time, sys
from pygame.locals import *

def drawItem(windowSurface, x, y):
    pygame.draw.polygon(windowSurface, RED, ((0+x, 100+y),(100+x, 100+y), (50+x, 50+y)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(windowSurface, GREEN, ((0+x,100+y),(100+x,100+y),(100+x,200+y),(0+x,200+y)))


pygame.init()

windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Lab 9")

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
GRASS = (26, 82, 26)
SKY = (179,237,255)

color = SKY
flag = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    windowSurface.fill(SKY)

    drawItem(windowSurface,200,120)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, GRASS, (0,300,500,500),0)

    house = ((0+50, 100+50),(100+50, 100+50), (50+50, 50+50), (50+100, 50+100))

    for i in range(3):
        pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface,color, house[i], 80)  

    if flag == False:
        color = WHITE
        flag = True
    elif flag == True:
        color = BLACK
        flag = False

    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: I know you're just playing around with it at the moment, but a good habit to get into is to use the length of lists and tuples when iterating over them. So rather than `range(3)`, you should use `range(len(house))` - this will iterate over all items in `house`; so if you decide to add an item to it, the loop will loop over all items, rather than just the first 3.

Comment: ok I'll try to get used to that, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already discovered how to test for the type of an event (checking whether `event.type == QUIT`).

You can extend this to check whether it's a mouse button click. Stick this in your `for event in pygame.event.get()` loop:

```
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    flag = not flag # This will swap the value of the flag
```

Then get rid of the `flag = True` and `flag = False` lines below, since you don't need them anymore. Also get rid of the time.sleep() call; or at least change it to a reasonable frame rate (like `time.sleep(0.2)` = 50 frames per second).

Comment: More documentation on events and all the different types can be found here: http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html